# SSAS Dimension process failed

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap, olap-cube

Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.

The datasource, 'Ruban Cube', contains an ImpersonationMode that is not supported for processing operations.

Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Ruban Cube', Name of 'Ruban Cube'.

Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Student', Name of 'Student' was being processed.

Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Dept ID' attribute of the 'Student' dimension from the 'MultidimensionalProject2' database was being processed.

Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit the data source and change the impersonation setting to anything but Impersonate Current User